# ...ну(,) типа(,) катапульта

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна запятая?

`Может, что-нибудь другое нарисовать? Ну(,) типа(,) катапульта.`

Comment: На стене рисовать нельзя! Катапульт? А что это?

Comment: @Sharon А с чего вы взяли, что на стене? Имелась в виду одна игра на телефоне/компьютере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы склоняете слово "катапульта", то слово "типа" является частицей, выраженной наречием, со значением, подобным слову "вроде". И запятая тогда нужна только перед "ну".

Если вы не склоняете слово "катапульта", то слово "типа" является междометием и отделяется запятой как от "ну", так и от других слов.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет склонять: *типа (чего?) катапульты*.

Есть два варианта, оба без запятой:

> Для быстрой идентификации типа инфекционного агента.
>
> Для быстрой идентификации типа «инфекционный агент».

Comment: Не, падеж менять не надо.

Comment: Рисовать будете типа? Или катапульту?